# this.store.create wont fire inside ajax call

Tags: sencha-touch, extjs

I simply am trying to update local storage but inside the Ext.Ajax.request I cant call this.store.create(). How do I call the this.store.create function inside the success: area of the Ajax call. Many thanks for your help.

```
  login: function(params) {
    params.record.set(params.data);
    var errors = params.record.validate();

    if (errors.isValid()) {

        var myMask = new Ext.LoadMask(Ext.getBody(), {msg:"Please wait..."});
        myMask.show();

        //now check if this login exists
        Ext.Ajax.request({
           url: '../../ajax/login.php',
           method: 'GET',
           params: params.data,
           form: 'loginForm',
           success: function(response, opts) {
              var obj = Ext.decode(response.responseText);      
              myMask.hide();    
              //success they exist show the page
              if(obj.success == 1){
                //this doesn't work below
                                    this.store.create(params.data);
                this.index(); 
              }    
              else{
                 Ext.Msg.alert('Incorrect Login'); 
              }
           },
           failure: function(response, opts) {
              alert('server-side failure with status code ' +     response.status);
              myMask.hide();
           }
        });  
    }
    else {
        params.form.showErrors(errors);
    }
},
```

Comment: What's the error?  Do you get a JavaScript exception?  It might be a scoping problem, your "this" pointer might not be pointing to what you think it is.  Also the docs mention an add method for stores but not a create.  What version of sencha touch are you using?

Comment: Im using sencha 1.1 I guess I need to reference the store with its full store name? ie: loginDetails.store.create(params.data); would that be correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Javascript, 'this' keyword changes its meaning with the context it appears in.

When used in a method of an object, 'this' refers to the object the method immediately belong to. In your case, it refers to the argument you passed to Ext.Ajax.request.

To work around this, you need to keep an reference of the upper level 'this' in order to access its 'store' property in an inner context. Specifically, it looks like this:

```
var me = this,
    ....;

Ext.Ajax.Request({
...
success: function(response, opts) {
              var obj = Ext.decode(response.responseText);      
              myMask.hide();    
              //success they exist show the page
              if(obj.success == 1){
                me.store.create(params.data);
                this.index(); 
              }    
              else{
                 Ext.Msg.alert('Incorrect Login'); 
              }
           },
});
```

Comment: Thanks very much. I will need to figure out how I reference this. as its setup it a more complex fashion. Is there a way to reference your stores at anytime? Like : myStoreName.store.create(params.data).

Comment: I'd just do `var store = this` in any "top level" method of the store wherever needed. [Here](http://bonsaiden.github.com/JavaScript-Garden/#function.this)'s a good place to read about 'this' keyword.

Comment: I should have also just used by data store rather than a ajax call inside a controller. mvc